# first-child selector does not select the first accordion-body

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less

The first-child selector (LESS) does not work for me. I have already tried different approaches but found none that works.

It does not select the first accordion-body and sets it to display:block. Without the first:child selector it works, but then all accordion bodys are open. But Only the first one should be opened.

What am I doing wrong?

LESS:

```
.accordion.product {
    &:first-child{
        .accordion-body{
            display: block !important;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="faq">
  <div class="accordion product">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <strong itemprop="name">
          Question 1               
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body schedule">
        <p>Answer 1</p>                
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion product">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <strong itemprop="name">
          Question 2                
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body schedule">
        <p>Answer 2</p>                
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE (Full code)

HTML:

```
<div id="faq">
    <?php if($faq->numRows && $faqCategory->numRows): 
        $faqCategoryResult = $faqCategory->fetchAllAssoc();
        $faqResult = $faq->fetchAllAssoc();

        // get the category id
        foreach($faqCategoryResult AS $category): 
            $categoryId = ($category['title'] == $entry->field('titel')->value() ? $category['id'] : '');

            if($categoryId): ?>
                <h2 class="sectionheading">Häufig gestellte Fragen (FAQ)</h2>
            <?php endif; 

            // get the faq's matching the category id above
            foreach($faqResult AS $faq): 
                if($faq['pid'] == $categoryId): ?>
                    <div class="accordion product" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <strong itemprop="name">
                                    <?= $faq['question'] ?>
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer">
                                <?= $faq['answer'] ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach;

        endforeach; 
    endif ?>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
section#container{
  #faq{
    .accordion.product {
        &:first-child{
            .accordion-body{
                display: block !important;
            }
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical description of the problem.

Comment: It does not select the first accordion-body and sets it to display: block. Without the first:child selector it works, but then all accordion bodys are open ;). But only the first one should be opened.

Comment: Put that in your question and title, not in the comments.

Comment: already done ;)

Comment: is working for me https://jsfiddle.net/sgxp5jv8/ check if you have another style

Comment: @stalin It does not work for me. The first accordion is not selected and the body is not set to block. Without the first-child selector it works (for all accordions). So the general css should be ok.

Comment: so show us a full code so we can see the issue

Comment: Working for me too.

Comment: As far as I know you're doing nothing wrong. It looks like more an inheritance issue. I suggest you inspect the code to search which properties - not only the first but all - '.accordion-body' classes are being inherited.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  added the complete code above.

Comment: i meant complete HTML/CSS code including any other CSS that may affect :) not PHP

Comment: @TemaniAfif To recognize the html structure this should be enough. Just ignore the PHP..

Comment: yes but you already put the HTML structure and am sure the issue is coming from other CSS ... so we would like to see it working .. can you provide snippet  ? link ?

Comment: It works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzNjye

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have copied the complete code in here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypOojX

Comment: I still think it's the first-child selector, because without it everything works (all accordion bodys opened).

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just found out that it works fine with: nth-child (2). The problem is definitely the: first-child selector. Does LESS generally have problems with this selector? I researched in Google: Looks like  I'm not the only one who has problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first-child selector does not work in this case because the element you want to target is **not** the first child of its parent. The `h2` is.

Use the `first-of-type` selector instead: https://codepen.io/yinken/pen/EoZoBN

Answer (score -3):

do it this way :)

```
 #faq {    
    .accordion.product {
        &:first-child{
            .accordion-body{
                display: block !important;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is already like that. But I omitted the #faq in my question to save space. Does not work anyway ..

Comment: can I have the live link of it where it is deployed?

Comment: https://www.academyofsports.de/de/fitness/fitness-c-lizenz.html Check the FAQ-Section.

Comment: tell me the actual issue you are facing I will fix it accordingly.

Comment: The goal is that the first accordion is open.

Comment: Which accordion you are using? basically it is not a CSS issue then it is a class missing issue only.

Comment: You might have to append an "opened" class to first "accordion-group"

Comment: No, it's definitely not a missing class. As I said, it works without the: first-child selector. I just found out that it works fine with: nth-child (2). The problem is definitely the: first-child selector.